# Spring boot redirects from hostname to local ip address from discovery | Embedded Tomcat | Zuul proxy

Tags: spring-boot, reverse-proxy, spring-security-oauth2, microservices, service-discovery

I'm developing an application base on a micro service architecture.

We have a few microservies: *oauth2*, *hello-web*, *discovery server* (eureka) and *reverse proxy* (zuul). The *oauth2* (authentication server sing on) and *hello-web* are behind the same *reverse proxy* with different path. Url to them are provided by *discovery server* (**serviceId** in zuul).

Simple application is here: https://github.com/akhmelov/test-zuul-oauth2

*Reverse proxy* is located on localhost:8083

- *oauth2* has route: /uaa/**
- *hello-web* has route: /hello-web/**

We met 2 problems during development:

1. When user hit to localhost:8083/hello-web, it forwards request to *hello-web* microservice. On the first request the user is unauthenticated, so *hello-web* service should redirects to localhost:8083/uaa/ (for log in user)

   Our problem is that during the first request (when user is unathenticated) *hello-web* redirects not to *localhost* but to ip  10.2.8.11:8083/uaa which is the same as in discavery server. It changes serverName. We checked x-forward-host in *hello-web* by debugging is **localhost**, so the serverName is changed in *hello-web* **but where (how to disable it)? and how hello-web knows about gateway's ip from eureka?**
2. When user hit instead of localhost:8083/hello-web to 10.2.8.11:8083/hello-web (where 10.2.8.11 is ip of *reverse proxy* from *discovery server*).On the first request (when user is unauthenticated) *hello-web* redirects to 10.2.8.11:8083/uaa (*oauth2* server) which redirect to 10.2.8.11:8083/uaa/login, when user fills in password it redirects to 10.2.8.11:8083/uaa and user get HTTP 404.
   If user do the same without *reverse proxy* (I mean if *hello-web* is on localhost:8080, *oauth2* is on localhost:8087 and during first request *hello-web* redirects directly to localhost:8087 without *reverse proxy*) everything works fine. **Why does it happen? How to fix it?**

We spend a couple of days trying to find solution or similar questions with no result, did we miss something?

Note:

- My /ect/hosts:

> 127.0.0.1 localhost
>
> 127.0.0.1 some_my_computer_name

- Discovery server (Eureka "Instances currently registered with Eureka")

> Application   AMIs    Availability Zones  Status
>
> GATEWAY   n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - 10.2.8.11:gateway:8083
>
> HELLO-WEB n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - 10.2.8.11:hello-web:8080
>
> UAA   n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - 10.2.8.11:uaa:8087

- We know about cookies
  **spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/#_testing_the_oauth2_client**
  and from the same page

> The context path has to be explicit if you are running both the client and the auth server on localhost, otherwise the cookie paths clash and the two apps cannot agree on a session identifier.

Sorry for poor english

Answer (score 0):

I found issue about this problem. There are also advices how to fix it https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1108